# Incorporating img src into a div class

Tags: html

The object referred to in this div class is an image.

```
<div class='shapes'>
<div class="object512450" data-left="75%"></div>
</div>
```

The url of the said object is:

```
https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg
```

How to incorporate this url into the div tag?

Comment: Its a part of xml template. The object described is a jepg image. That should appear in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="object512450" data-left="75%"><img src ="https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg" width="300" height="200"/></div>
```

Comment: It gave the following error: The reference to entity "id" must end with the ';' delimiter.